# Intermittent issues with wake from sleep/suspend: 24.04 ThinkPad E14 i5

Tags: suspend

Once every 10 wake ups or so all pointing devices (touchpad, trackpoint, touchscreen) will be inoperative

Once every 20 wake ups or so the laptop will not come out of sleep and needs to be restarted with a long press of the power button.

What kind of logs should I examine/post here to help debug this issue.

Thank you!

- ThinkPad E14 G4 i5
- 6.6.0-14-generic
- Ubuntu Noble Numbat (development branch) 24.04

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying out Ubuntu Noble Numbat 24.04 and cant get systems to suspend/hybernat. Looks like a problem with graphics cards. Ex:

62.902609] rfkill: input handler disabled
[   66.477582] nouveau 0000:17:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nve6_fuc084 failed with error -2
[   66.477646] nouveau 0000:17:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nve6_fuc084d failed with error -2
[   66.477652] nouveau 0000:17:00.0: msvld: unable to load firmware data
[   66.477660] nouveau 0000:17:00.0: msvld: init failed, -19
[  186.923093] systemd-journald[406]: /var/log/journal/2087ae98f5c4469eb62e372277f06288/user-1000.journal: Journal file uses a different sequence number ID, rotating.